# Making matrix in php with form html

Tags: php, forms, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

can you help me with this problem, i want make matrix with 2 forms, the first form is for how much is row and column is needed and second form is use for input value of array, 
I was stuck in how to display it but if there are other mistake please tell me... thx u :))

this for input row and column

```
<form method="POST" action="prak_10.php">
Masukkann n : <input type="text" name="bilangan_n">
<br>
Masukkann m : <input type="text" name="bilangan_m">
<input type="submit" name="submit" style="background: red;color:white;border-style: none;padding: 5px;" name="" value="Hasil">
```

and this for input value of matrix

```
<?php 
$n = $_POST['bilangan_n'];
$m = $_POST['bilangan_m'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
?><form method="POST" action="prak_10.php">
    <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            for ($j=0; $j < $m; $j++) { 
                echo "Masukkan nilai array baris : ".$i." kolom : ".$j.": <input type='text' name='nilai[][]'><br>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Hasil">
</form>
<?php }
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['nilai']); $i++) {
for ($j=0; $j < count($_POST['nilai']); $j++) { 
    echo $_POST['nilai'][$i][$j]." ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}print_r($_POST['nilai']);
?>
```

Comment: If you want feedback on your code quality, please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change This line

```
echo "Masukkan nilai array baris : ".$i." kolom : ".$j.": <input type='text' name='nilai[".$i."][".$j."]'><br>"
```